# Conversión de una matriz de excepción de error de cadena LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, array, string

Estoy tratando de obtener una consulta de mi base de datos, el detalle que me lo arroja en array mi consulta es el siguiente:

controlador:

```
   $folios_5 = DB::table('dependencias_turnadas')
->leftJoin('solicitudes', 'dependencias_turnadas.fk_solicitud', '=','solicitudes.id')
->select('solicitudes.Folio')->whereIn('fk_secretaria',[5])->get();
```

la variable lo mando en un data para pasar los datos en un PDF

```
     $data = [
   
    'folio_5'=> implode(',',json_decode(json_encode($folios_5),true)),
    
];

dd($data);

return PDF::loadView('administration.PDFs.FCCE_folios_turnados', $data)->setPaper('a4','landscape')->stream('FCCE_folios_turnados.pdf');
```

en mi blade lo pongo en una tabla: Blade:

```
       </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>
      @foreach($folio_5 as $f5)
      {{$f5}}
      @endforeach
    </td>

  </tr>
  </table>
```

no pongo la tabla completa ya que solo quiero un dato.

ya probe e investigue como tratar de convertir el array en cadena, es decir de tener este resultado de:

```
    [{"Folio":978},{"Folio":179},{"Folio":203}]
```

pasarlo a 978 , 179, 203.

probe con las sintaxis de json, json_encode, json_decode, implode, array, print_r, var_export;

```
     // 'folio_5'=>json_encode(json_decode(json_encode($folios_5))),
// $data = json_encode($data);
// // $datas = print_r(json_decode($data));
// $datas = array($data);
// // $datas = implode(" ", $data);
```

y  no se que mas puedo probar, o no se realmente en que me equivoque, ya que si paso la variable de la consulta normal sin nada de sintaxis de json me sale lo siguiente, con un dd(); venta este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si ya lo mando en mi blade de pdf me sale el siguiente error:

ErrorException htmlspecialchars() espera que el parámetro 1 sea una cadena, objeto dado

y no se si es por el foreach de mi blade.

alguien me podría apoyar??

Comment: Por qué haces esto? `implode(',',json_decode(json_encode($folios_5),true))`. No te conviene más tener una colección que un array? Sespués de todo, en la vista podrías hacer `@foreach($folio_5 as $f5) {{$f5->Folio}} @endforeach`. Y de todos modos, en el caso de poder serializar la colección a un array multidimensional, ¿no estarías queriendo imprimir un array en el html cuando haces `@foreach($folio_5 as $f5) {{$f5}} @endforeach` en vez de `@foreach($folio_5 as $f5) {{$f5["Folio"]}} @endforeach`?

Comment: lo hago para obtener los valores que deseo, además no me conviene tenerlos en array ya que la persona que lo quiere que sus datos salgan de forma de matriz; además ya lo intente con el forearch y no e resulta me arroja problemas. y no tiene caso que lo haga de esta forma {{$f5["Folio"]}} por que en la consulta ya lo estoy indicando que es lo que deseo, es como si hiciera esto {{$f5->Folio}}